# $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I wanna show, that if $f(x)$ is a [primitive polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)) we have the following is equivalent: $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ if and only if it is irreducible over
$\Bbb Q$.

The first direction we can show by contraposition. We suppose $f(x)$ is a reducible polynomial over $\Bbb Q[x]$. So if we write $f=g \cdot h$ we have that $g$ or $h$ are $\in \Bbb Q^*$. And because $\Bbb Q^* \subset \Bbb Z^*$, we are done. Now for the other side I have some trouble to show it. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you know Gauss lemma about the contents of polynomials ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^*=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}\mid q\neq 0\}$. $\mathbb{Z}^*=\{1,-1\}$. How is $\mathbb{Q}^*$ contained in $\mathbb{Z}^*$? Also, $f$ and $g$ may not “live” in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so that factorization may not even make sense as a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: If you mean "If $P$ and $Q$ are primitive polynomials over the integers, then product $PQ$ is also primitive", so sadly no

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)